# geodesics, covering map and its lift

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Followings are given problems.

---

Let $f:(M,g)\rightarrow (N,h)$ a covering map that is a local isometry, and let $p\in M$. If $\gamma:[0,1] \rightarrow N$ is a geodesic such that $\gamma(0)=f(p(0))$, then we can lift $\gamma$ to a geodesic $\tilde{\gamma}$:[0,1]→M a geodesic with $\tilde{\gamma}(0)=p(0)$

of course one  can see that $\gamma(t)=f(p(t))$, so that $\tilde{\gamma}(t) = p(t)$ for $t \in[0,1]$

---

I want to prove this statement. How we can prove this?

Comment: What exactly is $p(t)$?.

Comment: p is a point, in the region in $[0,1]$.

Comment: I figure out how to prove this statement. I will upload soon

Comment: Actually this statement is related with cartan hadamard theorem, you can find many relevant textbook and sources online.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A possible proof is as follows. The fact that $f$ is a covering map means that $f$ is a topological covering map (and thus a local homeomorphism), and also a local diffeomorphism and a local isometry. The theory of (topological) coverings tells us that $\gamma$ can be lifted to a continuous map $\widetilde\gamma:[0,1]\rightarrow M$, i.e. we have $f\circ \widetilde\gamma = \gamma$. Now, the fact that $f$ is a local diffeomorphism tells us that $\widetilde\gamma$ is smooth, since $\gamma$ is smooth and being smooth is a local property. Finally, the fact that $f$ is a local isometry tells us that $\widetilde\gamma$ is geodesic, since $\gamma$ is geodesic and being geodesic also is a local property.